# ckeditor tengo un problema con la configuración de las entities

Tags: php, javascript, codeigniter, ckeditor

Estoy configurando el `config.js` de CKEditor en CondeIgniter para que envíe los caracteres HTML, pero no envían correctamente las etiquetas HTML `<p>`, `<strong>`, etc.

Puse la siguiente configuración:

```js
/**
 * @license Copyright (c) 2003-2012, CKSource - Frederico Knabben. All rights reserved.
 * For licensing, see LICENSE.html or http://ckeditor.com/license
 */

CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
    // Define changes to default configuration here.
    // For the complete reference:
    // http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config

    config.basicEntities = false;
    config.entities_additional = '#1049';
    config.entities = false;
    config.specialChars = [ '&quot;', '&rsquo;', [ '&custom;', 'Custom label' ] ];
    config.specialChars = config.specialChars.concat( [ '&quot;', [ '&rsquo;', 'Custom label' ] ] );
    // The toolbar groups arrangement, optimized for two toolbar rows.
    config.toolbarGroups = [
        { name: 'clipboard',   groups: [ 'clipboard', 'undo' ] },
        { name: 'editing',     groups: [ 'find', 'selection', 'spellchecker' ] },
        { name: 'links' },
        { name: 'insert' },
        { name: 'forms' },
        { name: 'tools' },
        { name: 'document',    groups: [ 'mode', 'document', 'doctools' ] },
        { name: 'others' },
        '/',
        { name: 'basicstyles', groups: [ 'basicstyles', 'cleanup' ] },
        { name: 'paragraph',   groups: [ 'list', 'indent', 'blocks', 'align' ] },
        { name: 'styles' },
        { name: 'colors' },
        { name: 'about' }
    ];

    // Remove some buttons, provided by the standard plugins, which we don't
    // need to have in the Standard(s) toolbar.
    config.removeButtons = 'Underline,Subscript,Superscript';
};
```

con el `config.entities = false;`  ya me acepta los caracteres especiales, pero las otras configuraciones las envía codificadas.

Por ejemplo, me guarda en la base de datos: `&lt;p&gt;`   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es la función de controlador

```php
public function create()
{
    $extra = array(
        'return' => "{$this->_route}index/",
        'success_message' => lang("{$this->_language}:submit_success"),
        'failure_message' => lang("{$this->_language}:submit_failure"),
        'title' => lang("{$this->_language}:create"),
    );
    //$this->streams = 'htmlspecialchars',
    $this->streams->cp->entry_form($this->slug_stream, $this->namespace, 'new', null, true, $extra);
}
```

Comment: Intentaste con `config.allowedContent = true;` pero creo que no se recomienda...

Comment: si o intente y no me funciono , sigue guardando las etiquetas con los simbolos &lt;p&gt; en ves de la etiqueta <p>

Comment: prueba con la documentación https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/latest/guide/dev_output_format.html